# Camera on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

We need a total map size of 1000x1000, but the VIEW part is only 100x100, how to do it? Can I somehow indicate the coordinates of the start of the VIEW screen and its end.
[image]

Comment: It is hard to help you out without seeing the code that you are currently using for the rendering. Otherwise the answer could just be "Yes, you can", which probably is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I've already answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721799/scrollable-board-for-html5-game-should-use-svgs-or-canvas/50745010#50745010

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ???

```js
Math.rad = function(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
};

let tilesTotalX = 200,
    tilesTotalY = 200,
    tilesVisibleX = 10,
    tilesVisibleY = 7,
    tileWidth = 20,
    tileHeight = 20;

let worldSize = {
    w: tilesTotalX * tileWidth,
    h: tilesTotalY * tileHeight
};

let windowSize = {
    w: tilesVisibleX * tileWidth,
    h: tilesVisibleY * tileHeight
};

let tiles = [];
for (let row = 0; row < tilesTotalY; row++) {
    tiles.push([]);
    for (let col = 0; col < tilesTotalX; col++) {
        let r = (Math.floor(0xFF * (row / tilesTotalY))).toString(16),
            g = (Math.floor(0xFF * (col / tilesTotalX))).toString(16),
            b = (Math.floor(0xFF * Math.random())).toString(16);
        tiles[row].push(`#${r}${g}${b}`);
    }
}

let angle = 0,
step = .3;

let circle = {
    x: Math.round((worldSize.w - windowSize.w) / 2),
    y: Math.round((worldSize.h - windowSize.h) / 2),
    r: Math.round(((worldSize.h - windowSize.h) / 2) * .8),
};

let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#f0f0f0";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, windowSize.w, windowSize.h);

let fps = 16,
    fpsInterval = 1000 / fps,
    then = Date.now();

(function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    let now = Date.now(),
        elapsed = now - then;
    if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
        then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);

        angle += step;
        angle %= 360;
        //console.log(angle);

        let windowPosition = {
            x: Math.round(circle.x + Math.cos(Math.rad(angle)) * circle.r),
            y: Math.round(circle.y - Math.sin(Math.rad(angle)) * circle.r)
        };

        let firstVisibleRowIndex = Math.floor(windowPosition.y / tileHeight),
            firstVisibleColIndex = Math.floor(windowPosition.x / tileWidth),
            lastVisibleRowIndex = Math.floor((windowPosition.y + windowSize.h) / tileHeight),
            lastVisibleColIndex = Math.floor((windowPosition.x + windowSize.w) / tileWidth);

        let offset = {
            x: windowPosition.x - tileWidth * Math.floor(windowPosition.x / tileWidth),
            y: windowPosition.y - tileHeight * Math.floor(windowPosition.y / tileHeight)
        };

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(-offset.x, -offset.y);
        for (let row = firstVisibleRowIndex; row <= lastVisibleRowIndex; row++) {
            for (let col = firstVisibleColIndex; col <= lastVisibleColIndex; col++) {
                ctx.fillStyle = tiles[row][col];
                ctx.fillRect(
                    tileWidth * (col - firstVisibleColIndex),
                    tileHeight * (row - firstVisibleRowIndex),
                    tileWidth,
                    tileHeight
                );
            }
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
})();
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=200 height=140></canvas>
```